# Create new array value for each html element in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to turn this string:

```
> President Obama pointed blabla<br /> <br /> The only way I get this
> stuff <br /> <br /> I'm consulting with the Pentagon, with <br /> <br
> />
```

into this array: (new array element for each "`<br /> <br />`")

```
array (
[0] => President Obama pointed blabla
[1] => The only way I get this stuff 
[2] => I'm consulting with the Pentagon, with 
);
```

I tried to use `explode("<br /><br /> ", $string)` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `explode("<br /> <br /> ", $string)`  Note the space between the 2 `<br />`s.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to remove the first two characters of each line ("> "), concatenate all the lines, then do your explode (noting the missing space, as others have pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

In your case `explode("<br /> <br />", $string);` would work.

More generally, you can add: `$string = str_replace('<br /> <br />', '<br /><br />', $string);` before the previous line if you have some lines that are separated by `<br /> <br />` and some by `<br /><br />`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space between your `<br />` tags in the `explode` function.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it was a typo, you are missing a space in your explode() between each 
. Alternatively you could do:

```
$br2arr = array_filter(preg_split("/([\s\b]*<br \/>[\s\b]*)|([\s\b]*<br>[\s\b]*)/", $str));
```

Which should do what you want in any case/format